# how to select a pseudo-element and change status from :: after a :: before?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have this code html e CSS:

```css
[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before, [type=checkbox]:not(:checked)+label:before, [type=radio]:checked+label:before, [type=radio]:not(:checked)+label:before {
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 16px;
    float: left;
}


[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after, [type=checkbox]:not(:checked)+label:after, [type=radio]:checked+label:after, [type=radio]:not(:checked)+label:after {
    content: '';
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox subfield" for="gdpr_21215">
::before
Privacy Policy 
::after
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="gdpr_26839" name="gdpr[26839]" value="Y" class="av-checkbox gdpr subscribe-newsletter">
```

I'm using selenium with python to click but it doesn't work i use this:

```html
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Y'][id='gdpr_21215'][name='gdpr[21215]']").click
```

I read that javascript must be used to simulate but I did not understand how

Comment: Are you trying to click on the `label` element? Or change the actual `html` of the element?

Comment: I'm trying to click but after my code, it tells me not selected

Comment: If you are trying to click the checkbox use it's id: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[id="gdpr_26839"]').click()`

Comment: don't work this error   File 
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a Javascript click to click your desired element and work around the `ElementNotInteractable` exception:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# first invoke WebDriverWait and wait for the element to exist
checkbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "gdpr_26839")))

# use Javascript to click checkbox
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkbox)
```

You may need to modify the selector method `By.ID, "gdpr_26839"` if this does not work. Something such as `By.XPATH, //input[contains(@id, 'gdpr')]` might work better, depending on whether or not `gdpr_26839` is a unique / dynamically-generated ID.

Comment: If you are downvoting, please leave a comment and let me know how this answer can be improved. I acknowledge that Javascript is not the first-choice or best practice for this issue, but the based on the user's problem description, this is a workaround, not statement of best practices.